# Create new dataframe with max value from each cell per column out of a set of dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, max

I have a code that is looping through a list and spits out a dataframe for each iteration of the loop. Each of these dataframes is the same size (# of columns/rows). I want to create a new dataframe that contains the max value for each position in each column between all of the dataframes. In the code below, MRS_response_df are the newly generated dataframes that I need the max values from.
[image]

Example:

```
df_1 = 1 2 3 4
 0     2 2 2 2
 1     3 1 2 5

df_2 = 1 1 3 4
 0     2 3 5 9
 1     1 8 3 4

output = 1 2 3 4
 0       2 3 5 9
 1       3 8 3 5
```

Code Example:

```
data = 0
for i in dataset:
   #do stuff

    for i in column:
        
        print('Max Response Spectrum: ' + str(i) + ' out of ' + str(len(column)))
        y = accel_df[accel_df.columns[i]]
        MRS_frequency, MRS_response = MRS(t, y, Q, fn)
        MRS_frequency_df[MRS_frequency_df.columns[i]] = MRS_frequency    
        MRS_response_df[MRS_response_df.columns[i]] = MRS_response

 data += 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one way:

```
pd.concat([df1, df2], keys=[1,2]).max(level=1)
```

Output:

```
   0  1  2  3
0  1  2  3  4
1  2  3  5  9
2  3  8  3  5
```

Answer (score 1):

use `.where` and `combine_first()`:

```
df1.where(df1>df2).combine_first(df2).astype(int)

    0   1   2   3
0   1   2   3   4
1   2   3   5   9
2   3   8   3   5
```